# Generate pdf with images

Tags: google-apps-script

## Good day:

I am facing the following problem.
I have the following script to generate pdf:

```
function doGet(e) {
  if (e.parameter.function == "createPDF") {
    var sheetName = e.parameter.sheetName;
    var spreadsheetId = e.parameter.spreadsheetId; // Get the spreadsheet ID from the parameter
    var sheet = getSheetByName(spreadsheetId, sheetName);

    if (sheet) {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
      var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
      var pdfUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + spreadsheetId + "/export?format=" + e.parameter.type + "&size=0&fzr=true&portrait=false&gid=" + sheetId;
      var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(e.parameter.folderID);
      var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(pdfUrl).getBlob().setName(e.parameter.filename + "." + e.parameter.type);
      var newFile = folder.createFile(blob);
      var fileUrl = newFile.getUrl(); // Get the Google Drive file URL
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(fileUrl);
    } else {
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("Sheet not found");
    }
  }
}

function getSheetByName(spreadsheetId, sheetName) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  return sheet;
}
```

But in my sheet I have images and when I generate the pdf, the column that has images appears blank, the images are results of the formula =buscarv that consults another sheet that I use as a database of my images "=image( )"
Can you help me with my query?

Comment: About `But in my sheet I have images and when I generate the pdf, the column that has images appears blank.`, when I tested your script, I confirm that the created PDF data includes the images in and over the cells. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: What happens is that in a sheet I have the image base with the function =image()
In another sheet I do a =buscarv() to bring the image into the cell and that sheet is the one that I export to pdf, but the column of images appears empty

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I would like to recommend updating your question by including more information.

Comment: I updated my question, I hope now you can help me

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about the detail of `the images are results of the formula =buscarv that consults another sheet that I use as a database of my images "=image( )"`?

Comment: Of course, in a sheet of my book sheet, I have all the images of my drive that I bring with the function "=image()".
In another sheet I have a data structure and a signature column in which I apply the formula "=lookup()" that looks for the image data and gives me the image in the cells as a result.

When exporting the sheet to pdf with the provided script, the fields that do not have images seem normal to me, the problem is with the column that has the images, which appear empty.

Comment: `=buscarv` For those, like me who are wondering what is `buscarv`... it is a Spanish translation for `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although, unfortunately, I cannot imagine your spreadsheet from your reply, when I tested a sample spreadsheet including `=IMAGE("imageURL")` with your script, it seems that the image is correctly included in the exported PDF data. I apologize for this situation. In this case, it is required to know the method for correctly replicating your situation.